# C++ Getting values from file into array

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void make_array(ifstream& num, int (&array)[50]);

int main()
{
    ifstream file; // variable controlling the file
    char filename[100]; /// to handle calling the file name;
    int array[50];

    cout << "Please enter the name of the file you wish to process:";
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "\n";

    file.open(filename);

    if (file.fail()) {
        cout << "The file failed to open.\n";
        exit(1);
    } else {
        cout << "File Opened Successfully.\n";
    }

    make_array(file, array);

    file.close();

    return (0);
}

void make_array(ifstream& num, int (&array)[50])
{
    int i = 0; // counter variable

    while (!num.eof() && i < 50) {
        num >> array[i];
        i = i + 1;
    }

    for (i; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << array[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

I am trying to read values from a file to an array using `fstream`. When I try to display the contents of the array, I get 2 really big negative numbers, and then the contents of the file.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: I don't know what kind of values you're trying to read, but `get` reads single bytes (for reading numbers formatted as string, use `num >> array[i]`). Single bytes in C++ usually have the type `char`, and reference parameters need to match the type (no automatic type conversion possible).

Comment: Also, don't use `while (!eof())`. Replace it with the actual input operation.

Comment: I am trying to get int values. I am assuming the num >> array[i] only works with strings?

Comment: `num >> array[i]` works with any supported data-type, including int

Comment: Files never contain int values, files are composed of bytes. You can *encode* an int into bytes in a binary form or as text, and to read them you need to know how they where encoded. I'm pretty sure you mean the latter (i.e. you can read the number when opening it in a text editor), so yes you need indeed `num >> array[i]` (i.e. `get` is the wrong function).

Comment: alright. So now when I try to display the contents of the array, I get 2 really big negative numbers, and then the contents of the file. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: @user2905256 It's probably because you didn't replace the `!eof()` part with the input operation thereby making the program *not* have undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, if there were 50 sucessfully read integers, then `i` would be equal to 50. The loop below starts at `i == 50` and dereferences an address at that index, which is wrong because `array[50]` is one past the end of the array.

Comment: Could you provide an example file?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `num.get(array[i])` doesn't match any of its signatures.  [See `get` method description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/). What you want is this:

```
array[i] = num.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, you try to read an integer which is encoded as text. For this, you need to use `operator>>` (which reads any type encoded as string) instead of `get` (which reads a single byte):

```
num >> array[i];
```

Comment: Good point but the OP hasn't clarified whether the file is text or binary. My answer assumed binary, which may be incorrect.

Comment: I have edited my post to include all of my code. After populating the array with "num >> array[i]" the output from the array is a load of random numbers that don't resemble those in the .dat file. any ideas why?

Comment: more specifically, it is two rather large negative numbers, and then the contents of the file itself.